# Fetching a web page using C socket programming

Tags: c, proxy, network-programming

I am trying to build a proxy server in C. My problem is as follows,

I have a function fetch_response() which connects to example.com and queries the server with and HTTP GET request.

```
int fetch_response() {
   int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[4096];
    char *host = "example.com";

    portno = 80;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) error("ERROR connecting");
    const char * request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    n = write(sockfd,request,strlen(request));
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,4096);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,4095);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(buffer));
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

It runs fine when tested, for example

```
int main() {
    fetch_response();
    return 0;
}
```

However in my proxy server I am trying to handle multiple client requests,
so my main() functions is like,

```
while(1) {
   new_socket = accept(params);
   if(new_socket < 0) error("Error on Connect");
   pid = fork();
   if(pid < 0) error("Error on fork");
   if(pid == 0) {
      fetch_response();
      exit(0);
   }
   else close(new_socket);
}
```

In this case, I encounter a problem. I receive only the first 1328 bytes of the requested page no matter what my buffer size is. I have tested it with different domains and the result is the same. For example,in case of example.com, the expected result is,

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><h1> Example Domain </h1>
      < Some remaining body here >
</body>
</html>
```

But instead I get

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><h1> Example Domain </h1>
```

I cannot understand why this is happening. Please help.

Thanks !

PS : This is not the actual code of the proxy server. For debugging, I commented everything out and tested the code as above.

Comment: 1328 is approximately one Ethernet packet worth of data. You have to keep calling `read` until you've assembled the entire response.

Comment: I still don't get it. Why is the fetch_response() function working fine in the first case then?

Comment: Just a matter of luck and timing. When you call `read` there's never any guarantee on how many bytes you'll get. You can get anywhere from 1 byte to the size of the buffer. So the code should always repeat the `read` until the entire message has been accumulated.

Comment: @user3386109 I sorry to ask such a naive question but I'm new to C socket programming, how can you know when the entire message has been received?

Comment: There are multiple ways. If you're going to do this, you need to get the specification for HTTP. But for a toy program, use `recv` instead of `read`, and keep calling `recv` until the return value is 0. For TCP sockets, a return value of 0 means that the sender has closed the socket, which means no more data will be coming.

Comment: "*How can you know when the entire message has been received?*" This is defined by the application level protocol, HTTP in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose your reading code in a loop, something like this:

```
while (1) {
  bzero(buffer,4096);
  n = recv(sockfd,buffer,4095, 0);
  if (n < 0) {
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
    break;
  }
  if (n == 0) {
    // far end has closed socket
    break;
  }
  // printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(buffer));
  printf("%d\n", n);
  printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

This will keep reading from the socket until the far end closes it. For each time `recv` is called, it will return the number of bytes in the buffer. When it returns `0`, the far end has closed the socket and there is no more to be read.

Comment: Here is a full example that compiles and runs on Ubuntu 22.04.

https://github.com/angstyloop/c-web/blob/main/fetch-example.c . It contains compilation instructions for `gcc`.

If you don't have `gcc` installed already, you can install it on Debian-based Linux distributions (like Ubuntu) with `sudo apt install build-essential`.